# Не могу вызвать метод в класе php

Tags: php

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
class tapinambur {
    protected $mysqli = false;
    protected $db_name = '';

    function __construct($db_name) {
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
    }

    public function connectDB () {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '***', '***', $this->db_name);
        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }

    public function closeDB () {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

    function getNews() {
        connectDB();

        $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

        closeDB();

        return resultToArray($result);
    }
```

При обращении к `getNews()` пишет:

> Call to undefined function connectDB()

Помогите пожалуйста, только начал изучать ООП на *PHP*.

Версия *PHP*: 7

Answer (score 5):

В классе вызов вашей функции надо делать через `$this`  т.е `$this->connectDB();`
Тоже самое касается  метода `closeDB()`.

Более подробно читайте [ТУТ](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php)